# How can I copy a column into a row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have several rows of data that are entered manually. After hitting a specific VBA button, the data is transferred to another sheet, the sheet is then password protected, and then form is cleared.

How can I copy a column into a row, rather than the version I've come up with?

There are multiple sheets, one with the data, and others that it needs to archive to, depending on where the data was entered.  Sheet names are "active run" and "11A", "11B", etc.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    
    'Time check
    If IsEmpty(Range("D7").Value) = True Then
    MsgBox "No Time Stamp!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
     Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'name check
    If InStr(1, (Range("R7").Value), "<Choose one>") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Select a name from the pull-down menu", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
     Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("11A Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("11B Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("12A Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("12B Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("13A Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    Worksheets("13B Run Data").Unprotect "password"
    
    
    
    If MsgBox("This will clear all data!" & vbCr & "Do you wish to proceed?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Warning!") = vbOK Then
       
    
    'Name
        
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7").Copy
    With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    
    'Date
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AC8").Copy
    With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    
    
    'Time
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("AD8").Copy
    With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    'Molds-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D10:F10").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G10:I10").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                 .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Molds-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K10:M10").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N10:P10").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Molds-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R10:T10").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U10:W10").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
              .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    'Blowheads-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D11:F11").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G11:I11").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Blowheads-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K11:M11").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
               .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N11:O11").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Blowheads-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R11:T11").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U11:W11").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    'Blanks-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D12:F12").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G12:I12").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Blanks-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K12:M12").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N12:P12").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Blanks-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R12:T12").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U12:W12").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Rings-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D13:F13").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G13:I13").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Rings-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K13:M13").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N13:P13").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Rings-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R13:T13").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U13:W13").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Guides-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D14:F14").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G14:I14").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Guides-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K14:M14").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N14:P14").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Guides-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R14:T14").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U14:W14").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Baffles-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D15:F15").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G15:I15").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Baffles-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K15:M15").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N15:P15").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Baffles-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R15:T15").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U15:W15").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Plungers-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D16:F16").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G16:I16").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Plungers-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K16:M16").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N16:P16").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Plungers-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R16:T16").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U16:W16").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Thimbles-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D17:F17").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G17:I17").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Thimbles-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K17:M17").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N17:P17").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Thimbles-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R17:T17").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U17:W17").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    'Funnels-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D18:F18").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G18:I18").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Funnels-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K18:M18").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N18:P18").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Funnels-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R18:T18").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U18:W18").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    'Bottom Plates-11
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("D19:F19").Copy
            With Sheets("11A Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("G19:I19").Copy
            With Sheets("11B Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Bottom Plates-12
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("K19:M19").Copy
            With Sheets("12A Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("N19:P19").Copy
            With Sheets("12B Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    '*****************************************************************************
    'Bottom Plates-13
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("R19:T19").Copy
            With Sheets("13A Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Sheets("Active Run").Range("U19:W19").Copy
            With Sheets("13B Run Data").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    '*****************************************************************************************
    
    
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("D7") = ""
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R7") = "<Choose one>"
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("D10:I19") = "0"
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("K10:P19") = "0"
    Sheets("Active Run").Range("R10:W19") = "0"
    
    MsgBox "Form Cleared"
    
    
    Else
    MsgBox "Canceled."
    
    End If
    
      Range("D10").Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
    Worksheets("11A Run Data").Protect "password"
    Worksheets("11B Run Data").Protect "password"
    Worksheets("12A Run Data").Protect "password"
    Worksheets("12B Run Data").Protect "password"
    Worksheets("13A Run Data").Protect "password"
    Worksheets("13B Run Data").Protect "password"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: On Blowheads-12 `Sheets("Active Run").Range("N11:O11").Copy` should that be `N11:P11` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process each worksheet in turn. Loop through the source rows 10 to 19 and calculate the destination column.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Const PWD = "password"

    'Time check
    Sheets("Active Run").Activate
    If IsEmpty(Range("D7").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "No Time Stamp!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'name check
    If InStr(1, (Range("R7").Value), "<Choose one>") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Select a name from the pull-down menu", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If MsgBox("This will clear all data!" & vbCr & "Do you wish to proceed?", _
       vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Warning!") <> vbOK Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsAR As Worksheet
    Dim ar(1 To 1, 1 To 3), c as Long, r As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long, d As Long, k As Long
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    Set wsAR = Sheets("Active Run")
    With wsAR
        ar(1, 1) = .Range("R7").Value2 ' name
        ar(1, 2) = .Range("AC8").Value2 ' date
        ar(1, 3) = .Range("AD8").Value2 ' time
    End With

    ' sheets 11A,11B,12A,12B,13A,13B
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 11 To 13
        For k = 0 To 1
            Set ws = Sheets(n & Chr(65 + k) & " Run Data") 'A is chr(65)
            ws.Unprotect PWD
            lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(, 3) = ar
            
            ' calc col 11A=D(4) 11B=G(7) 12A=K(11) 12B=N(14) 13A=R(18) 13B=U(21)
            c = 4 + (n - 11) * 7 + (k * 3)
            For r = 10 To 19
                ' dest cols 10=E(5) 11=H(8) 12=K(11) 13=M(14) etc
                d = 5 + (r - 10) * 3
                Set rngSrc = wsAR.Cells(r, c).Resize(, 3)
                Set rngDest = ws.Cells(lastrow, d).Resize(, 3)
                rngDest.Value2 = rngSrc.Value2
                'Debug.Print ws.Name, r, rngSrc.Address, rngDest.Address
            Next
            ws.Protect PWD
        Next
    Next

    With wsAR
        .Unprotect PWD
        .Range("D7") = ""
        .Range("R7") = "<Choose one>"
        .Range("D10:I19,K10:P19,R10:W19") = "0"
        .Protect PWD
        MsgBox "Form Cleared"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: What values do I need to change to move the selected area down a few rows?  I believe its the clear area at the bottom (.Range("D10:I19,K10:P19,R10:W19") = "0"), and the r callout ( For r = 10 To 19), but just wanted to check.

Comment: @humungotron, Yes that clears the area used in the `For r = 10 To 19` loop so that line needs to be amended to.

Comment: Okay, something else is messing this up.  I have another sheet that has a 10 cell offset, and I'm seeing this replicated in this sheet.  Everything pastes, but its offset 10 cells to the left.

Comment: @humungotron The destination column is `d = 5 + (r - 10) * 3` so the -10 needs to change to the first r value.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Working perfectly once again